# Complicated about JTable

Tags: java, swing, calendar, jtable

I would like to know whether it is possible to make database columns to appear as rows into a JTable.

Graphically , this is what I mean, it is for a timetable:

Database

```
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
|Monday(8.30 -10.30) | Monday(10.30-12.30) | Tuesday(8.30-10.30) | Tuesday(10.30-12.30) |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Available           | Available           | Unavailable         | Available            |
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

JTable

```
+--------------------+-----------------------+
|Available           |  Unavailable          |
|--------------------|-----------------------|
|Monday(8.30-10.30)  |  Tuesday(8.30 - 10.30)|
|--------------------|-----------------------|
|Monday(10.30-12.30) |                       |
|--------------------|-----------------------|
|Tuesday(10.30-12.30)|                       |
+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: not easy job, simple forgot about coding something about shedule, personal calendar e.i., don't reinvent the wheeel, there are free project too

Comment: sure, (nearly :-) everything's possible - show us what you tried so far and where exactly you got stuck

Answer (score 2):

Possible - Yes.  Easy - probably not.

You'll basically be making `select * from [table]` queries and iterating through the results.  You'll want to look at these:

- [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)
- [ResultSet.getMetaData()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29)
- [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)

(I'm assuming you know the basics about querying a database)

So when you add your information to your table, use:

```
    JTable table = new JTable();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
    ResultSet rs; // actually have your result set here
    ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
    while(rs.next()){
        Object[] info = new Object[meta.getColumnCount()];
        for(int i = 0; i < meta.getColumnCount(); i++){
            info[i] = rs.getObject(i);
        }
        model.addColumn("Result" + rs.getRow(), info);
    }
    add(table);
```

Comment: This is not even an answer, you're suggesting him to make an obvious query and then look at some methods. How does this help him show the rows as columns?

Comment: @george_h Yes it is an answer.  The question was "is it possible" and the answer is "yes".  Everything else is extra information with the intent on helping the OP figure out where to go and post a more specific question once they come across one.  If the OP has a more specific question, please comment or edit the question to reflect.

Comment: After re-reading, I guess he could have been a bit more specific. Maybe mentioning an SQL query.

Comment: @george_h Updated to address your concerns.  You made me spend more time than I wanted on a question the OP probably won't look at.  :(  Well, as they say, "And remember it's for posterity..." :)

Comment: Nick>>thanks for those codes ; indeed, my post was not complete; it is that on how display those columns data into rows based upon their their content in database

Comment: @Nick Rippe I wasn't trying to force you to spend more time, but your update is good. There's no reason now why Mithilesh wouldn't be able to solve this.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at ResultSetTableModel.java which does most of the work you describe. For source code, just google it.

Answer (score 1):

- Put all of the column names in a List<String>.
- Use the List to construct your SQL query.

  Select (comma delimited string from List<String>)
      from table
      where ...
- Loop through the Available / Unavailable `ResultSet`, and put the corresponding column name from the List<String> into your table model as either available or unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

It's not simple to do. You want (assuming I understand well) an agenda, with days as columns and hours as rows ?

I think the better way is to extends AbstractTableModel as many times as you need (for example  DayTableModel, WeekTableModel...) Here is a good example : http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing.table/extendsAbstractTableModelCustomclasstype.htm

I hope I helped you.

EDIT: Didn't understand that. Anyway, I guess the best way to do it is to extends AbstractTableModel (but just once).

Comment: no friend, in database days are columns and hours as rows having value of either available or unavailable.  However, while displaying, I want only two columns, available and unavailable.  Its as if the opposite.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've understand. My mistake was about the JTable. I thought you wanted days as columns and hours as rows ^^ But I get it now. Did you find the solution now ?